# Need help in WMIC Output

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmic

How can I format the output file for below `wmic` command? I need to rework on failed machines

```
wmic /node:@D:\input.txt /Output:"D:\Result.html" nicconfig where (IPEnabled=TRUE and DHCPEnabled=FALSE) call SetDNSServerSearchOrder ("9.1.1.1","10.1.1.1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell? You collect it in a variable like this:

```
$output = & wmic '/node:@D:\input.txt' nicconfig where '(IPEnabled=TRUE and DHCPEnabled=FALSE)' call SetDNSServerSearchOrder '("9.1.1.1","10.1.1.1")'
```

***if*** you're running `wmic` in the first place. Which you're not.

In PowerShell use the proper cmdlets for WMI operations (e.g. [`Get-WmiObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject)):

```
$dnsServers = '9.1.1.1', '10.1.1.1'
$computers  = Get-Content 'D:\input.txt'

$output = Get-WmiObject -Computer $computers -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled=True AND DHCPEnabled=False' |
          ForEach-Object { $_.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($dnsServers) }
```